# SQL copying only one row from one table to another - how to set where statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am writing a trigger to copy one row to another table before delete. I can't seem to get it to work with just one row. I have looked at many posts here and they set the where statement to be something like where id = existingId; or something like that. I can't seem to figure out how to get the trigger to just copy one row. Or how to tell it what the current row is. I can't use a specific value from the table (like id, name, etc) in the where statement, because I won't know which row is to be selected. Thank you!

This is what I have so far:

```
create or replace TRIGGER archive_tbl
BEFORE DELETE ON STUDENT
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ARCHIVE_STUDENT (stdid, fname, lname, mi, majorid, address, city, state, zip, phone, advid)
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE ????
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle, you can use `:old.col1` to [refer to the row](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_delete.php) that is about to be deleted.  Be sure to declare the trigger `for each row` if you do.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (:old.col1, :old.col2, :old.col3)
```

For SQL Server, you can use the `deleted` [special table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).  It contains the rows that were deleted.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM deleted
```

Comment: oh my goodness. I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now. I knew it was something simple I was missing. :( I am using Oracle so your first example worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

On triggers, you can have a reference to the `new` and `old` transition variables that let you see the values of the record (in the case of deletes, only old).

You can't select the values from Student, since you already deleted it, so either you use old.column for each of the columns or you query deleted table, like Andomar refers in his answer.